# How to create ajax object as array or for group of request?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to create ajax object for every request and call function per request or object using jquery.

example in javascript

```
xhr[rand] = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr[rand].open("post", "base64upload", true);

xhr[rand].upload.addEventListener("progress", function (event) {

    if (event.lengthComputable) {
         $("#"+barid).css("width",parseInt( (evt.loaded / evt.total * 100), 10) + "%");
         console.log("progress="+barid);
    }
    else {
        alert("Failed to compute file upload length");
    }
}, false);

xhr[rand].onreadystatechange = function (oEvent) {  
  if (xhr[rand].readyState === 4) {  
    if (xhr[rand].status === 200) {  
      $("#"+barid).css("width","100%");

    } else {  
      console.log("Error : Unexpected error while uploading file");  
    }  
  }  
};
```

here i have added eventlistner to each object. I want do same thing in jquery

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use [`.promise()`](https://api.jquery.com/promise/) for this.

You can add a promise to the upload function. This way you could run functions like `upload.done(function(e) { /* do stuff */ });`

The [`$.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) in jQuery has its build-in promise.
You can check if an ajax call succeeded with `xhr.done(function(e) { /* do stuff */ });`